# Python Queue double threading

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I am trying to run 5 threads which run another 10 threads each. Something like:

```
dictionaryFileQueue = Queue.Queue()
with open(dictionaryFile, "r") as wordsToCheck:
    for word in wordsToCheck:
        dictionaryFileQueue.put(word)

for wordToScan in wordsList:
#...some code

    dictionaryFileOpen = dictionaryFileQueue

    for i in range(10):
        i_thread = Thread(target=words_Scan_Start, args=(dictionaryFileOpen, wordToScan))
        threads.append(i_thread)

for thread in threads:
    for wordThread in thread:
        wordThread.start()

def words_Scan_Start(dictionaryFile, wordToScan):
    # Here I need to make an action with "wordToScan".
    # But in 10 threads "range(10)" and use the same "dictionaryFileOpen" for every thread.
    #...............
```

BUT, I need that each `wordToSacn` thread uses its own `dictionaryFileQueue`, which is comes from common source (`dictionaryFileQueue` at first line). Because when I'm starting all the threads, it all use just one Queue. But I need copy of Queue for every `wordToScan`. How can I make each `wordToScan` uses only copy of Queue and start its enumeration from the first line? How to make it use its own Queue which is coming from the common source?

Comment: I miss `queue` point , why you need ? if you got process tail how to run multiple threat at same time?

Comment: Queue is analog for `dictionaryFile.readline()`. I need it just to make every thread read only the next line of file if some thread is already read that line.

Comment: Separate  every queue but how to split jobs to every thread ? Need  create thread manager for which success or failed and returned data ! You can't draw a apple without drawing tree before.

Comment: When I was using `dictionaryFile.readline()` this code worked fine, until I ran few hundreds of threads and got an error about "to many files oppened". Each thread worked with its own file.open() and read its own lines. But here I'm trying to replace `file.readlin()` with Queues.

Comment: with + for, `wordsToCheck = open(dictionaryFile, "r")` of course  need a try except for checking file and reading data status.

Comment: I would suggest using a [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) from [multiprocessing.dummy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) (which uses threads) - this is quite simple to use and from there it is a small step to using processes which can much better utilize multiple CPU (with some constraints)

Comment: Could you provide an example of wordToScan and/or wordlist and a prototype example of the function words_Scan_Start pls?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that was so easy to do.
Just need to paste this part:

```
dictionaryFileQueue = Queue.Queue()

for word in linesOfDictionary:
    dictionaryFileQueue.put(word.strip())
```

Inside of this part:

```
for wordToScan in wordsList:
#...some code

    # INSTEAD OF THIS LINE BELOW
    #dictionaryFileOpen = dictionaryFileQueue
```

And add this code at the begining of the script:

```
openDictionaryFile = open(dictionaryFile, "r")
linesOfDictionary = openDictionaryFile.readlines()
openDictionaryFile.close()
```

instead of:

```
#dictionaryFileQueue = Queue.Queue()
#with open(dictionaryFile, "r") as wordsToCheck:
    #for word in wordsToCheck:
        #dictionaryFileQueue.put(word)
```